# Chrome appears to create workable local ICE candidates even when STUN/TURN servers are down--can I use them somehow?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, libnice

I'm using the `chrome://webrtc-internals/` URL to debug our WebRTC application behavior when the STUN/TURN servers are down.  One interesting thing I'm noticing is that under "Stats Tables" there appear to be good, "peerreflexive" local ICE candidates being generated, for example:

```
Cand-2rjZ43jF (localcandidate)
Statistics Cand-2rjZ43jF
timestamp   10/24/2017, 9:19:39 AM
ipAddress   192.168.59.1
networkType unknown
portNumber  40555
priority    1845501695
transport   udp
candidateType   peerreflexive
```

The thing is this candidate never comes to me through the `onicecandidate` callback.

Is this just an internal quirk of Chrome or is there a way to get these perfectly good candidates?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how this ICE candidate is generated. But as you can see, the candidate points to `192.168.59.1` which is your LAN IP address. So this candidate will only work for connecting to someone at the same LAN as you're computer.

Comment: Yes this is in fact the standard scenario in our application--which is designed more for LAN usage.  Really we don't want to use ICE/STUN/TURN at all, but it's a required part of WebRTC.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a required part. It depends on use case. You can setup a call between two browser parts without defining any STUN/TURN servers. I haven't tried to make a call to another computer on the same network, but it should work the same way

Comment: Well part of the signaling portion of the protocol is to exchange ICE candidates, and when the STUN/TURN server doesn't respond, Chrome doesn't generate any "icecandidate" events, from what I'm seeing.  I posted the question because curiously enough, the webrtc-internals URL does show some candidates and I'd love to attempt to use them.